# How to update a lib that can't be found

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, vlc

I am trying to build VLC player. My only hiccup is with `libavcodec`. It wants 57, I have 56.

```
configure: error: Requested 'libavcodec >= 57.37.100' but version of libavcodec is 56.56.101.
```

So I went to grab a ppa from someone who has it

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/experimental
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libavcodec57`

Cool. Now it is installed. I run `./configure` again, but i still get hit with the same warning. What am I doing wrong? I cannot uninstall libavcodec56 because it does not seem to exist anywhere. I even got the aptitude GUI just to double check, and I cannot find it.

Comment: You can install a local copy of FFmpeg and then point the vlc compile process towards this. Technique illustrated in great depth here: http://www.andrews-corner.org/linux/ubuntu/vlc.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the libavcodec-dev package (for development files) not just the libavcodec runtime binary.

```
sudo apt install libavcodec-dev
```

Comment: i would but that lib package is stuck at 4.2 and i need 4.9

Comment: The -dev package in the PPA matches the runtime because they're always automatically built from the same source.  You installed the runtime, now install the -dev package to build VLC player against it.